# Video streaming with php. Why is the response slow?

Tags: php, symfony, video-streaming, html5-video

I have a big problem. I have a video streamer site. The site has public and private videos, private videos can be seen after purchase.

Here you can see the directory structure:

```
    /public_html
    |__/vendor
    |__/src
    |__/public
    |__/product
       |__/sample-video
          |__/video.mp4
```

Well, as you can see the videos are located outside the public folder. The goal is to make them inaccessible directly.

Here is the twig:

```
<video id="myVideo">
   <source src="/products/12?video=10&cache={{ random(50, 10000) }}" type="video/webm" />
   <source src="/products/12?video=10&cache={{ random(50, 10000) }}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The video controller:
https://pastebin.com/sne1mSHH

And the video stream logic:
https://pastebin.com/2Sxd7Nqq

Here's the problem:

I'm going to the site. You switch between pages. Perfectly good. I go to a page with a video still good and after I start the video, the page is not good.. The page just loads and does nothing. I can't switch between pages anymore. I have to close the incognito mode and start a new session.

Until now I thought that the session lock was the problem, but I close the write session.

I tried opening the video in a new tab. Also the error is until the video stream is finished, the page does not handle the request.

So while the video is playing, while I can't send a new request.
What else can I attach to make the error more transparent?
Help pls!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personnally not use *PHP* to stream the video. The problem is that you'll have to many *PHP* processes locked for reading and streaming a big file instead of handling logic. You will also have a *PHP* timeout during this process.

Instead, I would use the **Sendfile** module:

- You install an *Apache* module or other kind of *Sendfile* module for your web server, *NGINX* or whatever.
- In *PHP*, you do the logic for the protection and just send a HTTP header to say you want *Sendfile* to handle the streaming. This way your *PHP* code stops running and its the web server that handles the transmission of the file.

Something like this:

```php
<?php
if (has_access_to_the_video($file))
{
    // Send the right HTTP headers.
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    // Make sure you have X-Sendfile module installed on your server.
    header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);
    exit;
}
else
{
    // Generate your 403 error or whatever.
}
```

This may help you:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html then search for `sendfile` in the page.
- https://github.com/mostafaznv/php-x-sendfile
- [PHP File Serving using X-Sendfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432123/php-file-serving-using-x-sendfile)
- https://www.h3xed.com/programming/how-to-use-x-sendfile-with-php-apache

#### Another remark regarding your video sources

For the `<video>` tag, you are declaring two `<source>` elements, one with `type="video/webm"` and the other with `type="video/mp4"` but both point to the same URL. In your PHP logic, I don't see any handling of the desired content type so **your server is probably returning the same video file for both codecs and this is problematic**. I would add the video content type in the URL and on the server side, do the internal redirection with *Sendfile* to the correct file (MP4, OGG, WEBM, etc). If the browser requests a `WEBM` file and recieves a `MP4 H.264` instead, I assume it will not load correctly.

It seems that `MP4 H.264` is widely handled by know, so you could just stick with one source. See the current support here:

- https://caniuse.com/mpeg4
- https://caniuse.com/webm
- https://caniuse.com/?search=ogg

Comment: Thank you the answer!!!

I have litespeed installed on my server. In principle, would that work?  

https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:internal-redirect

The "public directory" is the root directory. The products folder is outside the public folder.
Can only X-Sendfile access a file outside the root directory?

Comment: Well, I never worked with *Litespeed*, but regarding the wiki page you mentionned, it seems that you have to put your videos below the document root and not outside (for security reasons). I would put them in a subfolder such as `videos/64hbGiKrw7eQbk` so that it's not easy to guess then also add a rewrite rule to deny direct access to the files (as mentionned in the wiki) and then return the HTTP header to initiate *Litespeed* to serve the file instead of *PHP* with `header('X-LiteSpeed-Location: /videos/64hbGiKrw7eQbk/video-48392.mp4');`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The error is still there, but only in Chrome. In Firefox the workaround works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Laszlo : I added an explanation about the `<source>` tags which are probably loading the same video file, probably with the wrong codec. Hope this is your second problem. I think that browsers don't all decide to download the MP4 file if you declare them several sources. One browser might prefer OGG or WEBM. Check https://caniuse.com/mpeg4 ,  https://caniuse.com/webm and https://caniuse.com/?search=ogg and

Comment: Ohh.. THANK YOU very much! This solution is perfect and my problem is solved. I never thought before, that this could be a problem with ```<source>```.